# mysql query with join clause and group by clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I want this as result

```
------------------------------------------------------
c_name    |  c_id   | email_count | number_count |
-----------------------------------------------------
course1   | cid1234 |    7        |7             |
course10  | cid7489 |    4        |4             |
course9   | cid0987 |    2        |2             |
course5   | cid2321 |    2        |2             |
course6   | cid8905 |    1        |1             |
course2   | cid2134 |    1        |1             |
course3   | cid4352 |    1        |1             |
course7   | cid9087 |    1        |1             |
course8   | cid6574 |    1        |1             |
course4   | cid1244 |    0        |0             |
---------------------------------------------------
```

but i am getting result like this

```
------------------------------------------------------ -----------
c_name    |         c_id            | email_count | number_count |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
null      | cid1234                 |    7        |7             |
null      | cid7489                 |    4        |4             |
null      | cid0987,cid2321         |    2        |2             |
null      | cid8905,cid4352,cid6574 |    1        |1             |
null      | cid2134,cid9087         |    1        |1             |
null      | cid1244                 |    0        |0             |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have two databse tables name as **(course_master)** & **(search_course)** in one table course details are there, such as 
1.) course name as **(c_name)** ,

2.) course Id as **(c_id)** ,

In another table in that three coulombs are there

1.) course Id as **(c_id)** ,

2.)course sent on email as **(c_eml)** ,

3.) course sent on number **(c_num)** ,

such as

```
first table name course_master 
--------------------------
s.no | c_name  | c_id    |
--------------------------
1.   | course1 | cid1234 |
2.   | course2 | cid2134 |
3.   | course3 | cid4352 |
4.   | course4 | cid1244 |
5.   | course5 | cid2321 |
6.   | course6 | cid8905 |
7.   | course7 | cid9087 |
8.   | course8 | cid6574 |
9.   | course9 | cid0987 |
10.  | course10| cid7489 |
--------------------------
```

second Table Name is like search_course

```
-----------------------------------------------
s.no.|   c_id  |     c_eml        |   c_num   |
-----------------------------------------------
1.   | cid8905 |example@host.com  | 9999999999|
2.   | cid7489 |  any email Id    | any number|
3.   | cid0987 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
4.   | cid1234 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
5.   | cid2134 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
6.   | cid4352 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
7.   | cid1234 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
8.   | cid1234 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
9.   | cid2321 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
10.  | cid2321 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
11.  | cid1234 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
12.  | cid9087 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
13.  | cid1234 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
14.  | cid1234 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
15.  | cid6574 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
16.  | cid1234 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
17.  | cid7489 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
18.  | cid0987 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
19.  | cid7489 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
20.  | cid7489 | ------"--------  | -----"----|
```

i try my level best, i even tried very many join query but **i think the course ids are coming in group like for eml_count =  1 ,  their is 3 course Id in that row** ,  i am unable to get result what i want **(Course Name Accordingly)**.. soo please any one can try to write a mysql query for this it will be very great help for me thanks in advance ....

Comment: Provide your sql query also

Comment: What did you tried so far

Comment: Please post your query which you have written to achieve this.

Comment: i tryed very many diff query

one of them is 

{ SELECT B.c_name, A.c_id, COUNT(A.c_eml) AS email_count, COUNT(A.c_num) AS number_count 
FROM search_course A JOIN course_master B 
ON A.c_id=B.c_id 
GROUP BY B.c_name 
ORDER BY COUNT(A.c_eml) DESC, COUNT(A.c_num) DESC }

Comment: can u check my answer ..@A.Sharma

Comment: and when i apply query for single table just like 

 { SELECT c_id,  COUNT(c_eml) as email COUNT(c_nul) as number count FROM search_course GROUP BY fid ORDER BY count(c_eml) DESC, count(c_num) DESC }

by this also the same result but except course Name coloumn 

and i think this course Name comes as null because c_id are more then 1 in single cell

Comment: @Chanukya Please Provide Link Of Your Answer although i check and try very many solutions such as (left join, right join, inner join) from stackoverflow but no query is working in my case

Comment: just i want to know it is working or not  i tried my own..@A.Sharma

Comment: one sec sir i'll let you know

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this

```
select 
 c_name,A.c_id,
    count(c_eml) as 'ceml',COUNT(c_num) AS CNUMBER_COUNT
from #A(table 1) A
  left join #B(table_2)  B on
 A.c_id=B.c_id
group by
    c_name,A.c_id
```

Comment: no sir it is write an empty result....

Comment: can u try with left join ...@A.Sharma

Comment: join query is taking very much time as loading 
please sir wait meanwhile i'll let you know the result of that also in some minutes

Comment: ok carry on ..@A.Sharma

Comment: sir by left join i am getting course_name C_id,  But count of eamil and number i am getting as 0 instead of any number

Comment: And By Right Join I am Getting Course name and c_id as (null) and bt right join count result is getting as total count of email and number in one row only

Comment: see inner join will work based on matching records so if no records are not coming in the sense no matching records so ur count is conning ads 0..@A.Sharma

Comment: this is data issue ..@A.Sharma

Comment: sir can u please specify little bit to me that what type of  issue in data will creating that problem i mean acc. to me it seems very same as different examples which are on web 

so if you know more about this issue please  tell me sir

Comment: see  data no matching records are coming i want to know how u get that result please share that query ..@A.Sharma

Comment: can u share ur getting result query which ur showing in question ..@A.Sharma

Comment: actually sir in question i written sample data and sample table because i have about 1 lakh of data in my table and suppose i simply apply count query for one table such as 
SELECT c_id, COUNT(c_eml) ,COUNT(c_num) FROM course_search GROUP BY  c_id ORDER BY COUNT(c_eml) DESC, COUNT(c_num) DESC 

by this query only i am getting the same data but except c_name coloumn in result table

i mean of same data  is

Comment: here u are not using course_master  table and u are counting only from course search table then what is the use of other table ..@A.Sharma

Comment: sir if you don't mind please share your gmail id

Comment: sorry in my company there is o access for gmail just tell me use of master table in ur query  are not using that table ..@A.Sharma

Comment: oke no problem sir

Comment: actully sir what i am saying is that i am getting moe then one id in single row is that the problem because c_id for both table is not same then \

Comment: c_id for both table is not same means we cannot join that two tables either u can join by id only ..@A.Sharma

Comment: SELECT C_NAME,A.C_ID,COUNT(C_EML) EMAIL_COUNT,COUNT(C_NUM)NUMBER_COUNT FROM #A A
INNER JOIN #B B ON A.C_ID=B.C_ID GROUP BY C_NAME,A.C_ID
..@A.Sharma

Comment: obviously it will take time because that is not correct data  y i am saying join will work only matching columns and master table records must be there in course table then u need foreign key for c_id this and all prior u need to do then only we can proceed or else performance  wise it is really impact the screen 
this much discussion for small question please accept my answer for this much effort or upvote ..@A.Sharma

Comment: sir your efforts are very helpfull for me but when i am clicking on uparrow on your ans it is showing this "" thanks for the feedback! votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publically displayed post score."" 

thanks a ton for helping me out .............

Comment: sir srry about this but can u please tell me how to accept any ans i didn't use that  much......

Comment: below voting it will be there tick mark if u click that it will show green color tick ..@A.Sharma

Comment: y u removed acceptance ..@A.Sharma

Comment: srry sir two ans are there na so by mistake your ans will removed

Comment: ok thank  u so much ..@A.Sharma

Answer (score 0):

try like that......

```
select c_name,A.c_id,count(c_email) email_count,count(c_num)number_count A from course_master B 
inner join search_course on A.c_id=B.c_id group by B.c_id
```

Comment: srry but this is not working if you didn't give the suffix to table name liek course_master A inner join search_course B then how it can run,,,

Comment: ohh..sorry for that i update the answer with suffix..actually i have tested with some demo data and i replace tha data with table name and forgot to give the suffix to the table

Comment: ji your query will be like this as correct formate SELECT c_name,A.c_id,count(c_email) AS email_count, count(c_num) AS number_count FROM course_master B inner Join search_course A on A.c_id=B.c_id group by B.c_id  

but this also writtens as an empty result